# Platform Events

Tags: xpages, custom-event

I cant make plaform event work. When in Chrome I cant see any request being made (but if I do XSP.PartialRefreshGet it works. Maybe I have a library version problem?). Here is the code.

```
<xp:button id="button1" value="ClickMe">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
        <xp:this.script><![CDATA[XSP.publishEvent("publishString", "hello", "string");]]></xp:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
<xp:label value="Label" id="label1"></xp:label>
<xp:platformEvent id="platformEvent1" eventName="publishString">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onevent" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:if (context.getSubmittedValue() == null)     getComponent("label1").setValue("No value submitted");
else getComponent("label1").setValue(context.getSubmittedValue());}]]>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:platformEvent>
```

PS: can someone upload uncompressed XSPClientDojo library please. It doesnt exist in domino directory for some reason.

Comment: I'm not sure but I don't think an uncompressed version is readily available. I don't think IBM distributes it uncompressed for copyright reasons. I could be wrong though.

Comment: There is the uncompressed version for debugging. You might find it in [DominoProgramFiles]\osgi\shared\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.xsp.dojo_VERSION\xsp.dojo.jar file. Open this with an archiving utility (e.g. 7-zip) and navigate into "\resources\dojo-version\ibm\xsp\widget\layout\" folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

publishEvent is part of the support for XPiNC (XPages in the Notes Client), alongside methods like XSP.executeCommand. They deal with integration with the Notes client specifically, so they're best to ignore when doing proper browser development.

Dojo events are probably more what you're looking for: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/events/

Comment: Jesse is right. Platform Events can be used with XPiNC and they are actually designed for composite applications.